# Bootstrap divs are not next to each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just experimenting with my first Bootstrap project and but this one in the body:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But somehow, the two divs are just below each other and not next to each other aligned as they should be.

Does someone has an idea, what I did wrong?

Comment: Did you already check with e.g. Firebug or other web dev tool which css applies to your divs? E.g. if they have float left and correct size, and if bootstrap.css etc is included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you are properly adding the required files?  I put your code into a sandbox and it worked.  Here is the full html with the code you posted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Please go through [grid system in bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/G5vzgPoOyl)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/uqbpzpoo/)**, if you don't load your bootstrap.css correctly, the columns behave as you described. But if you do include it correctly, like **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/1m9nxcob/):**, you'll see they behave like you want. Just be sure to include bootstrap, from either a cdn or locally:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- or wherever you keep it -->
```